# How to add space in h1

Tags: css

```
#entry-wrap h1 {
background-color: #E94578;
color: #FFF;
}
```

How to add space before text in h1? At the momment the text is too close to the left edge.

Comment: You could use non-breaking-space too. checkout my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add some padding (`padding-left:5px;` or something)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a margin and adjust to your liking ( higher will increase the space).

```
#entry-wrap h1 {
    margin-left: 10px; /* Creates space on the outside of the element */
    background-color: #E94578;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#entry-wrap h1 {
  background-color: #E94578;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padding` OR `margin`.

[css padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

[css margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

**With padding :**

```
#entry-wrap h1 {
background-color: #E94578;
color: #FFF;
padding : 5px;
}
```

**With margin :**

```
#entry-wrap h1 {
background-color: #E94578;
color: #FFF;
margin : 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `padding-left`.

```
  #entry-wrap h1{
       padding-left : 20px;
  }
```

or you could use `&nbsp;` ( [Non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). )

```
 <h1>&nbsp; Your Title here </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some left margin

```
margin-left: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add padding to h1 =>

```
#entry-wrap h1 {
background-color: #E94578;
color: #FFF;
padding-left: 10px
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Less elegant, but you could just use `&nbsp` to create space before `<h1>` tag.